# F# compare quotations

Tags: f#

following prints "false"

```
let e1 = <@@ let d = 1 in d+1 @@>
let e2 = <@@ let d = 1 in d+1 @@>

printfn "%A" (e1 = e2)
```

The reason is that Var nodes are compared by pointer reference and not by structural equality.
Is there already implemented a way to compare quotations intuitively?

Comment: Converting quotations to string is not optimal performance-wise, and not correct either, as the full type information is not spit out in the output string...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many reasons why comparing quotations does not "work" by default:

- Quotations can contain references to values for which comparison may not be defined (e.g. if you create a quotation that captures some .NET object that does not support comparison).
- Quotations contain information about the location in the source code - so your two quotations are different simply because they are on different lines!
- There is a question whether you want to treat `(fun x -> x)` and `(fun y -> y)` as the same - logically, they are, but syntactically, they are not.

So, if you want to check whether quotations are equal, you'll just have to implement your own check. Something like this does the trick for the basic case you have in the example, but it does not handle all the cases:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let rec equal = function
  | Let(v1, ea1, eb1), Let(v2, ea2, eb2) -> 
      v1.Name = v2.Name && equal (ea1, ea2) && equal (eb1, eb2)
  | Var(v1), Var(v2) -> v1.Name = v2.Name
  | Lambda(v1, e1), Lambda(v2, e2) -> v1.Name = v2.Name && equal (e1, e2)
  | Call(None, m1, es1), Call(None, m2, es2) -> 
      m1 = m2 && (List.zip es1 es2 |> List.forall equal)
  | Value(v1), Value(v2) -> v1 = v2
  | _ -> false
```

Comment: Thanks, i have to implement my own comparison. I would like to be able to treat variable with different names but same type as equal. and object values. But I will have to collect these cases as the comparison goes and ensure correctness.

Comment: In theory, the thing you want is called "alpha equivalence" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence) and a useful trick to deal with it is to ignore the names of variables and just track a number (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_notation). In practice, I think you can just add two dictionaries mapping variable names to integers and then check equality of the numbers in the `Var` case.

Comment: I was thinking of implemented a sequence over quotations. If i encounter Var1 in first stream and Var2 in second, than subsequently if i encounter Var1 in the stream it must correspond to exactly Var2.